# Crop an image with a very big border radius

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Today I got a layout from a designer for a website.

On the background is a pattern over the whole body. 
The header image is curved croped on the right side.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I can't build that kind of radius with `border-radius` in CSS.
A PNG mask isn't an option, because the pattern must match.

Knows someone a special trick, to build that kind of `border-radius` in CSS?

Comment: Are you sure this is done with CSS only?

Comment: @Gendarme it is quiet possible ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a wrapper, position, radius and shadow can do something really close :

for more info  about border-radius:

> https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

```css
div {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px white, inset 0 0 15px gray;
  display:table;/* or inline-block/inline-table */
  overflow:hidden;/* clip content */
  border-radius:0  20% 20% 0 /80%;/* cut off basic border-radius */
  position:relative;/* bring at front so img doesn't fade behind body */
}
img {
  display:block;/* gap underneath .. or vertical-align:top/bottom */
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;/* let inset shadow of parent lay over it */
}
body {
  background:brown
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer (including the shadow)

Answer (score 2):

You can get this cropping circular if you offset the wrapper to the left and top (beyond the screen)

```css
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position:relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  left: -400px;
  top: -200px;
}
img {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a full circle, you could use a trick with pseudo elements.

Something like:

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius:50%;overflow:hidden;
  transform:translate(-20%, -20%); /*just for demo*/
}
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;height:60%;
  left:20%; width:80%;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/600);
  background-size:100% 100%;
```

```html
<div></div>
```